# O que significa "diam" em "elas 'diam' ao junco para o mato"

Tags: regionalismo, dialetos-insulares

O texto abaixo é o relato de uma senhora (1) habitante de Flores, Região Autônoma dos Açores a uma segunda pessoa (2) não identificada. Relato este feito no século XX.

> 1 "Oh grandeza, elas acartavam sargaço de lá debaixo do calhau, coitadinhas, que era para trazer para o estrume para as terras – está percebendo? –, para botarem nessas terras mais aí em baixo do Moldinho. Que o sargaço é estrume bom para batatas!"
>
> 2 "É mui bom!"
>
> 1 "E havia… Eu dizia: Oh, pobres das mulheres da Fajãzinha, são umas escravas, coitadinhas! O que elas trabalham! **Elas 'diam' ao junco para o mato**. **Elas 'diam' ao leite para o mato** – tinham o gado no mato –, **era preciso 'dir' de manhã cedo** ao leite. A gente…"
>
> 2 "Quatro horas, no Verão!"
>
> 1 "Às quatro horas, no Verão, que **elas 'diam' ao leite!** E eu dizia assim: "Jesus, (…) eu nunca queria ser da Fajãzinha"! Mesmo não gostava! Olhe, a gente não pode dizer…"
>
> 2 "Foi onde veio parar!"
>
> 1 "É verdade! A gente não pode dizer nada neste mundo. (…) E aqui é que estou há quarenta anos!"

Qual o significado de "dir" e "diam"?

Comment: Qual é fonte? Parece-me que é "ir" e "iam".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Dir*** é a variante local do verbo ***ir***. O diálogo reproduzido na pergunta é parte da recolha de falares regionais feita na Fajãzinha, Flores, Açores, no âmbito do [CORDIA-SIN, Corpus Dialetical para o Estudo da Sintaxe](http://www.clul.ul.pt/pt/recursos/226-corpus-syntax-oriented-corpus-of-portuguese-dialects-cordial-sin), e pode ser [ouvido aqui](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/som81.html). Está aqui um [conjunto de entrevistas na Fajãzinha](http://www.clul.ul.pt/english/sectores/variacao/cordialsin/flf_n.html), que inclui o diálogo reproduzido na pergunta. ***Dir*** e suas flexões repetem-se ao longo das entrevistas, e só como *ir* fazem sentido. A passagem seguinte é muito clara: o inquiridor pergunta se ***ia***, e o informante responde ***dia:***

> INQ1:  Mas, ***mas ia-se pondo*** do lado, era?
>
> INF1: ***'Dia-se' pondo*** de lado. ***'Dia-se' pondo*** a modos de lhe dar o sol para aquecer — não sabe?

Nas passagens seguintes, ***dir*** é verbo auxiliar, e só como ***ir*** faz sentido:

> INF: E ***'dia-se' buscar*** camas de musgo ao mato. ***'Dia-se' apanhar*** musgo no mato — está percebendo?
>
> INF: ***'Dia' ordenhar*** as vaquinhas, que o meu homem não
> podia — era mui doente. Eu ***'dia'*** ordenhar as vacas duas vezes no dia.

O mesmo se passa nesta passagem:

> INF: Diz que as lavandeiras [aves] que quando Nossa Senhora
> ***'dia'*** para o Egipto e mais o Senhor São José, elas ***'diam' escondendo*** as pegadas. Que foi naqueles anos que o Rei Herodes queria matar o Menino Jesus e elas ***'diam' escondendo*** as pegadas do
> animal para não ***'direm'*** à procura deles. Nunca ouviram isto?

A passagem seguinte é quase uma repetição da anterior. Mas agora a entrevistada usa também o pretérito perfeito, e temos um ***foram escondendo*** em vez do ***diam escondendo:***

> INF: Que são as avezinhas de Nossa Senhora. ***Foram Escondendo*** as pegadas do animal para não ***'direm'*** ao encontro de onde ele está.

Ao todo contei 65 ocorrências de flexões de ***'dir'*** e duas flexões de ***ir*** por parte dos informantes. Não sei se não terá sido quem transcreveu que se esqueceu de do ***d***.

Comment: Interessante!  Esta forma, imagino, originou na península já que *dir* também é a forma no asturiano (mas não no mirandês, curiosamente) com as formas na primera pessoa de *voi, fui, fuera/e, **diba, diré, diría, diendo, dío***.  É curioso que esta forma do infinitivo (com flexões correspondentes) também se conserve nas islas.  O pode ser uma inovação lingüística paralela?

Comment: @guifa Perguntas bem! A escrita na idade média tendia a ser fonética, e eu nunca encontrei ***dir*** em textos antigos. Estou mais inclinado para a hipótese de inovação paralela. O ***d*** também é muito ténue, quase como o ***th*** do ***there*** inglês. Vou incluir o link ao audio na resposta.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Parabéns.

Comment: @Centaurus Obrigado. Reparaste que a senhora no «está percebendo» da senhora? Não sabia que tinha resistido nos Açores.

Comment: Jacinto,  Não entendi bem.  O que resistiu nos Açores?  O "está" (terceira pessoa do singular) ou o "percebendo" ?  Suponho que o uso da terceira pessoa seja referente a "o senhor/ou a senhora está percebendo?", uma vez que nos Açores não usam a forma "você".

Comment: @Centaurus É o *percebendo*. Naquela situação, em Portugal quase toda a gente diria «está a perceber»? O uso do gerúndio naquela situação já foi a norma (pelo menos a norma culta). Entretanto foi substituído por *a + infinitivo*. Eu sabia que tinha 'resistido' no Alentejo e Algarve, mas não nos Açores.

Comment: Interessante.  Como "percebendo" soa muito natural aos meus ouvidos, eu nem percebi que em pt-PT o "estás a perceber" é a regra.