# Substituição do perfeito do indicativo pelo imperfeito do subjuntivo: “ficaste” por “ficasse”, etc em PT-BR

Tags: gramática, português-brasileiro, tempo-verbal, modo-subjuntivo

Tenho vários amigos brasileiros, e muitas vezes, quando trocamos sms, é usual virem escritas palavras que me fazem duvidar da sua correção gramatical. Por exemplo, numa última mensagem, uma amiga perguntou-me « *ficasse* com quanto?» em vez de «ficaste com quanto?», numa outra vez, outro amigo perguntou-me «*fizesse* [uma actividade]?» em vez de «fizeste [uma actividade]?».

A minha dúvida é se estas palavras realmente existem, ou se são apenas coloquialmente aceites quando já há alguma confiança entre as pessoas?

Obrigado

Comment: Não queres dar mais contexto? *Ficasse* e *fizesse* existem: são pretérito imperfeito do conjuntivo/subjuntivo. Exemplos: tu dizes, «e se ele ficasse com €500?»; o teu amigo responde «quê?! ficasse com quanto?»; «e se eu fizesse uma feijoada para o almoço?»  Agora só pelo que tu descreves, não dá para ver se era o conjuntivo que ele deveria usar. «Ermão» não vem nos dicionários. Talvez seja um modificação enfática do tipo de ***granda** (maluco, etc.)* e ***muita** bom* dos portugueses.

Comment: @Jacinto já adicionei mais informação. ;)

Comment: Obrigado, agora já está claro. Eu acho é que isto deveria ser duas perguntas separadas, uma para as conjugações, outra par o *ermão*. São dois assuntos completamente diferentes. E eu faria títulos mais explícitos, por exemplo: *substituição do perfeito do indicativo pelo imperfeito do subjuntivo (e.g. 'ficasse' em vez de 'ficaste')*; *Uso de 'ermão' em vez de 'irmão'*. Uma pessoa que daqui a uns meses tenham a mesma dúvida terá mais facilidade em encontrar as tuas perguntas se os títulos forem mais explícitos.

Comment: @Jacinto Segui a tua sugestão, e separei as questões.

Comment: Isso tudo parece erro tipografico de sms. Nada mais. Não creio que haja nenhuma substituição de verbos, nem nada disso. E que  brasileiros são estes? São do norte do Brazil? Ou do Sul? Nemhum brasileiro falam assim.

Comment: @Lambie Alguns são do Recife, outros de Belo Horizonte.

Comment: Eu acho que são erros tipograficos: nos dois casos mencionados por você, só tem uma letra diferente, ficasse por ficaste e fizesse por fizeste. isso não tem nada a ver com português "brasileiro". E meramente um erro de digitação. Ocorre frequentemente....

Comment: @Lambie a mim cheira-me mais a erro de pessoal que acha que é assim que se escreve. Erro de digitação ocorre uma vez em mil e não por duas pessoas seguidas...

Comment: Sim, pode ser que pensam que se escreve assim más na fala se ouve a letra T.

Comment: Eu acho que eles queriam escrever em pt-PT sem saber o correto uso. senão teriam escrito 'ficou com quanto?'

Comment: @Lambie Isso não é relativamente comum no Nordeste? Recife, por exemplo.

Comment: Comun no nordeste é o TU....mas aí aqui haveria um erro de DIGITAÇAÕ, credo. :)

Answer (score 3):

Não sei afirmar se essas grafias estão corretas, mas elas são muito comuns em partes do Brasil.

Sou brasileiro de Santa Catarina, no Sul do país, e é extremamente raro, no dia a dia, ouvir (ler) alguém falando (escrevendo), por exemplo: "*Tu fica**st**e com quantos reais após o pagamento?*" ou "*Tu fize**st**e aquele trabalho da faculdade?*", sendo esse uso mais reservado à escritas formais.

Em contrapartida, é muito mais comum ouvir (ler): "*Tu fica**ss**e com quantos reais após o pagamento?*" e "*Tu fize**ss**e aquele trabalho da faculdade?*" (no dia a dia, informalmente). Inclusive é bastante comum o uso de "tu ficou" e "tu fez", como por exemplo nas frases: "*Tu ficou com quantos reais após o pagamento?*" e "*Tu fez aquele trabalho da faculdade?*".

Sendo assim, como bem indicou @Jacinto, essa seria uma forma informal corrente do pretérito imperfeito em Santa Catarina (e possivelmente Rio Grande do Sul), utilizada somente na segunda pessoa do singular do pretérito perfeito. Não é uma substituição geral de todos os **st** por **ss** (e.g., *haste* é *haste*, e não *hasse*).

Digo isso principalmente sobre os dois estados mais ao sul do país (SC e RS), onde utilizamos muito mais o "tu" do que o "você". Já nos demais estados existe a predominância do uso do "você", então acredito que os exemplos que dei seriam mais raros, sendo mais comum ouvir (ler) frases como "*você ficou com quanto?*" e "*você fez uma atividade?*".

Comment: Claro, poderia se ficasse ou fizesse mas não como resposta a: //numa última mensagem, uma amiga perguntou-me « ficasse com quanto?// Teria de ser: (você) ficou com quanto ou (tu) ficaste com quanto. NUNCA se diria: ficasse ou fizesse NESTE contexto.

Comment: Se você não sabe se essas grafias estejam corretas, é impossível responder.....Nenhum brasileiro vai dizer: ficasse com quanto. Tem que ser: ficou ou ficaste. Ficou com quanto ou ficaste com quanto.

Comment: Eu particularmente falo "ficasse" ou "fizesse" o tempo todo. Sinceramente não sei se está errado ou não, mas não sou o único a falar dessa forma.

Comment: João, eu fiquei a pensar que havia aqui um mal-entendido qualquer. Mas descobri [isto](http://streetsmartbrazil.com/voce-ficou-tu-ficaste-tu-ficou-when-portuguese-hits-streets/). Só para esclarecer, tu dizes *eu fiquei, tu ficasse, ele ficou*? Talvez pudesses acrescentar alguns exemplos de frases completas à tua resposta.

Comment: Honestamente, acho que estou a ficar um bocado confuso. A maior parte dos comentários diz que é um erro de digitação, e tu, João, dizes que é normal... Depois de ler o link do @Jacinto acho que tens razão, mas parece haver algum desconhecimento, sobre como se fala em algumas regiões do Brasil, mesmo entre brasileiros. Porque será?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea , o Brasil é um país grande como o caraças. E mesmo em Portugal, sabes que na zona de Campo Maior se diz *vou a jantar* em vez de *vou jantar*, e que nos Açores há quem diga [*dia, diam* em vez de *ia, iam*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/o-que-significa-diam-em-elas-diam-ao-junco-para-o-mato/1782#1782)? Agora o que é curioso, e que os teus amigos que escrevem isso nem são do sul...

Comment: @Jacinto é verdade... =D Vou perguntar-lhes, acho que eles já não levam a mal.

Comment: João, isto será uma questão meramente fonética, de o ***st*** passar a ***ss***: *fica**st**e* > *fica**ss**e*? Acontece também com outras palavras, por exemplo *po**st**e* > *po**ss**e* (do gol/baliza por exemplo), *ha**st**e* > *ha**ss**e* (de bandeira)?

Comment: Caros, não há má vontade, nem acredito que seja erro de digitação. Eu apenas dei meu parecer com base na minha experiência de vida. Realmente acredito que seja erro, pois como falei, esse tipo de escrita/fala acontece apenas informalmente. Mas é, sim, bem comum. @Jacinto, a origem talvez seja fonética, dessa forma que descrevesse, mas não posso afirmar.

Comment: Mas o ***st*** > ***ss*** acontece só nesses casos (tu + pretérito perfeito)? Ou acontece também noutras palavras? Se acontecer também com outras palavras (e.g. haste > hasse), a origem deve ser fonética.

Comment: @Jacinto Só nesses casos que exemplifiquei mesmo (tu + pretérito perfeito)

Comment: Origen fonêtica?  para "Ficaste com quanto?". Até se "o pessoal" escreve assim a pronuncia nunca seria essa.....Voces ficam falando no préterito perfeito como se a pregunta fosse: Se você ficasse com....Dizer: "Ficasse com quanto" para "Ficaste com quanto", não é **o uso** do pretêrito perfeito....

Comment: @Lambie é exatamente essa a questão: é a forma errada de escrever e falar, mas é como muita gente escreve e fala, coloquialmente no dia a dia.

Comment: "Se você ficasse com....Dizer: "Ficasse com quanto" para "Ficaste com quanto" ", eu entendo que neste caso a pessoa apenas repete o verbo utilizado por quem pergunta. "Eu ganhei um dinheiro para dividir entre nós, e se você ficasse com 10 conto?" a pessoa querendo confirmar o valor diria "Ficasse com quanto?"

Comment: Elas podem ser comuns no seu Estado, mas não no Brasil.

Comment: @AndréLyra corrigi na minha resposta

Comment: João, na minha opinião a tua resposta juntamente com os teus esclarecimentos adicionais nos comentários esclarecem cabalmente a questão. Eu já votei, mas valeria talvez a pena incluir esses esclarecimentos na resposta. Nomeadamente que *tu ficasse* etc. é uma forma informal corrente do pretérito imperfeito em S. Catarina (exemplos de frases completas ajudariam); que é só mesmo na 2ª pessoa do singular do pretérito perfeito; não uma substituição geral de todos os *st* por *ss* (*haste* é *haste* e não *hasse*).

Comment: Outra coisa, eu acho que isto não é uma questão de correto/incorreto: é mais um regionalismo que se desvia da norma padrão.

Comment: @Jacinto Editei minha resposta. Gostaria de poder votar nos comentários mas acredito que minha reputação não permita.

Answer (score 1):

Ficasse: Entendo que neste caso a pessoa apenas repete a pergunta.

"Eu ganhei um dinheiro para dividir entre nós, e se você ficasse com 10 conto?"

A pessoa querendo confirmar o valor diria: "Ficasse com quanto?"

Para Fizesse a mesma coisa: "E se ele fizesse 10 horas de tais exercícios?" 
Respondendo com outra pergunta "Fizesse o quê?".

Comment: Isto foi o que a pergunta original me levou a pensar. Vê o meu comentário à pergunta. Mas entretanto o autor já clarificou que *ficasse* foi usado no lugar de *ficaste*, e *fizesse* no lugar de *fizeste*.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que "ficasse" como pretérito do indicativo é **sempre** inaceitável, mesmo coloquialmente. O correto é "ficaste", ou melhor ainda, já que o contexto certamente é o uso de "você" como segunda pessoa, "ficou".

"Ficasse" é imperfeito do subjuntivo, e somente imperfeito do subjuntivo.

Não é como "tu ficou" ou "você pegou, então está contigo", que são coloquialismos, inaceitáveis na linguagem formal, porém perfeitamente aceitáveis (e às vezes até obrigatórios) no coloquial.

Answer (score 1):

Em alguns estados do Norte e Nordeste ( Pará, Paraíba, por exemplo) usa-se a 2ª pessoa do imperfeito do subjuntivo em lugar do pretérito perfeito do indicativo , em contextos informais. Ex. Piorasse,  foi? Tu não eras assim! / Foi uma muvuca danada quando o marido chegou! Kkkk entendesse?!! Ficasse satisfeito com a explicação?
Não é questão de não saber conjugação correta. É questão de uso. Aprende-se : eu fiquei, tu ficaste , ele ficou etc. mas tem essa substituição no uso. E pode misturar tu com você na oralidade.Depende do contexto de uso Ex.: Tu chegou cedo? Pensei que você não vinha! Tava comemorando já! Kkk  Visse?

Comment: MUITO interessante. A primeira resposta que explica algo bem. Se vive um dia mais, se aprende um poco mais.